# Migrated question missing its "source"

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, migration

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/189465/usb-ps2-usb-thumb-drive-wtf) question is being shown as migrated, but it doesn't display from where it was migrated.
KronoS and Me [spotted this](http://chat.superuser.com/transcript/message/6195), and [Diago♦](http://chat.superuser.com/transcript/message/6204) confirmed that it come from [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/181919/usb-ps2-usb-thumb-drive-wtf-closed).

---

### Screenshot

[image: Shot of migrated question that doesn't show a source]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously now fixed. Accepting to make sure the question fades away...